# What do you call this "pushed in area" border effect?

Tags: interaction-design, terminology

It's common to use the terms drop shadows, inner shadows, glows, etc - these are all well known and understood

An effect you see all the time is:

1. a border around
2. on the top and left, it's a darker color
3. on the bottom and right, it's lighter than the color in (2)

[image]

Skeumorphically, it's symbolically as if the panel is **pushed in a few millimeters** and of course the falling light causes that side "edges" to be darker (perhaps even a small shadow) and on the far side lighter.

Often the panel "pushed in" is made slightly darker or different..

[image]

Anyway, we all see this everywhere -- but what's the best term for this?

As I say, there are clear popular terms for inner shadow, outer shadow, drop shadow, glow, frame, etc.  What the heck do you call this?

I can only think of using "emboss" or "pressed" or "pit" in some way; I don't know the answer.

---

*footnote - i quickly made the image above very badly for the sake of posting this question; I'd never use horrible corners and messy lines like that!!*

Comment: What about `well`?

Comment: What about inset shadow?

Comment: Honestly "tray" is a good of term as any. Makes sense.

Comment: Hey DA whassup - you know, it's definitely an iOS dev term; I really think it's pretty unclear to use that.  (Also - really it doesn't really look like a tray to me!)  I think Das has the answer..)

Comment: Hi passatgt .. you know, that does kind of make sense when you think about it; what do others think?  It tends to confuse me thought with "inner glow".  Also a shadow is only on two sides you know .. it's almost like two inner shadows, or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stylistically, the visual design term for that is **[debossing](https://www.google.com/search?q=debossed&safe=off&es_sm=91&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CEYQsARqFQoTCM_35OCZmMgCFdCiiAodMTANrw&biw=1176&bih=712)**.

Comment: This is fantastic.  (What the hell are you doing suggesting "tray" in the comment?  :-)

Comment: Sorry men I'd forgot to tick an answer here. Thanks again!  Wish I could tick both!!

Answer (score 5):

Bootstap uses the term "well" to describe these.
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells

> A well is a container in  that causes the content to appear sunken or an inset effect on the page.

Comment: nice one Das !!

Comment: Note that Bootstrap is using a slightly different effect, however. Instead of showing debossed edges, its using an inset shadow.

Comment: @DA01 True, it does differ depending exactly how you want it implemented. I will say that I have never heard a dev while wireframing describe an element as a debossed element, they simply say "a well". But when it comes down to it your answer is more accurate for this case. I think debossing may be a term more widely known by designers than devs, or perhaps "well" is just a more generic term.